# The issue with collection mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

I've got the strange issue with mapped collection caching.

Now I have two classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mods", catalog = "artfunpw")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
public class Mod implements java.io.Serializable {
***
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "mods") 
    @OrderBy("ReleaseDate desc")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
    public Set<ModVersion> getModsVersionses() {
        return this.modsVersionses;
    }
***
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mods_versions", catalog = "artfunpw", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "VersionNumber"))
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
public class ModVersion implements java.io.Serializable {
```

My Hibernate caching config is

```
    props.setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
    factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
```

When I run my select code for first time

```
Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<ModVersion> modVersions  = s.createQuery("select m.modsVersionses from Mod m")
                .setCacheable(true) 
                .list();
```

I got collection like

```
[arthur.khusnutdinov.mysitev2.pub.mods.db.ModVersion@4063fbec, arthur.khusnutdinov.mysitev2.pub.mods.db.ModVersion@7a0d599e, arthur.khusnutdinov.mysitev2.pub.mods.db.ModVersion@48087e35]
```

but on second call I am got collection of nulls:

```
[null, null, null]
```

What am I doing wrong and how to prevent nulls instead of expected objects?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, but it fixed after I re-wrote the query from

```
select m.modsVersionses from Mod m
```

to

```
select o from Mod m join m.modsVersionses o
```

But I don't know, why it's happened and why it cached with second query, because both of them are translated to the same SQL query

```
 select
        modsversio1_.id as id1_2_,
        modsversio1_.BuiltWithGameVersion as BuiltWit2_2_,
        modsversio1_.Description as Descript3_2_,
        modsversio1_.DownloadCount as Download4_2_,
        modsversio1_.DownloadCountExeFile as Download5_2_,
        modsversio1_.DownloadUrl as Download6_2_,
        modsversio1_.DownloadUrlExeFile as Download7_2_,
        modsversio1_.modId as modId10_2_,
        modsversio1_.ReleaseDate as ReleaseD8_2_,
        modsversio1_.VersionNumber as VersionN9_2_ 
    from
        artfunpw.mods mod0_ 
    inner join
        artfunpw.mods_versions modsversio1_ 
            on mod0_.id=modsversio1_.modId
```